# Let $A, B$ be sets. Show that $\mathcal P(A ∩ B) = \mathcal P(A) ∩ \mathcal P(B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A, B$ be sets. Show that $\mathcal P(A \cap B) = \mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B)$.

I understand what this question is asking. The power set of an intersection equals the intersection of two power sets. I just have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Show that every element from left side is in right side. And every element from right side is in left side.

Comment: How about double inclusion?

Comment: To get you started, if $X \in P(A \cap B)$ then $X$ is a subset of $A \cap B$. Therefore it is a subset of both $A$ and $B$. Therefore...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand the question now

Answer (score 4):

Let $X \in P(A \cap B)$.

Then each element of $X$  is an element of $A$ and $B$, hence $X$ is also in $P(A)$ and $P(B) \implies X \in P(A)\cap P(B)$.

Now

Let $Y \in P(A)\cap P(B)$.

Then $Y \in P(A) $ and $Y \in P(B)$. Therefore each element of $Y$ is an element of $A$ and $B$. Hence each element of $Y$ is in $A\cap B \implies Y \in P(A\cap B)$.

Notice that $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary, hence we have shown that any set in $P(A \cap B)$ is in $P(A)\cap P(B)$ and vice versa.

From this we can conclude that the two sets have identical composition and are thus equal.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$ is the set of all and only the sets which are at the same time subsets of $A$ and $B$. But by definition these are **exactly** the elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B)$.