# Does ℘(A ∩ B)=℘(A) ∩ ℘(B) hold? How to prove it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently working on some discrete mathematics work and I've encountered a question I'm not sure how to answer exactly. Precisely, I'm trying to prove that two power, intersected sets statements are equal to each other and my understanding of how to do that doesn't seem to be enough. The statements in question go as follows:

```
Determine whether, for any sets A and B, through proof, it is true that
                          ℘(A ∩ B)=℘(A) ∩ ℘(B)
where ℘ denotes a power set.
```

Should I make some form of example set to better understand how these statements are equivalent? Or even a venn diagram? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $S$ is a subset of $A\cap B$, is $S$ a subset of $A$? Of $B$? If $S$ is a subset of $A$ and of $B$, is $S$ a subset of $A\cap B$?

Comment: Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115482/let-a-b-be-sets-show-that-mathcal-pa-∩-b-mathcal-pa-∩-mathcal-pb/1116538#1116538