# Understanding the validity of this proof for interesection of power sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Link: [Let $A, B$ be sets. Show that $\mathcal P(A ∩ B) = \mathcal P(A) ∩ \mathcal P(B)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115482/let-a-b-be-sets-show-that-mathcal-pa-%E2%88%A9-b-mathcal-pa-%E2%88%A9-mathcal-pb)

In the first answer, particularly in this line:
"Let $Y \in P(A)\cap P(B)$.

Then $Y \in P(A) $ and $Y \in P(B)$. Therefore each element of $Y$ is an element of $A$ and $B$."

I don't see why this implies that $Y$ is an element of $A$, $B$. Clearly from an example I don't see it to be true either.

Let $A = \{0,1\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}$.
$P(A) = \{ \{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\},\{\}\}$ and $P(B) = \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{\}\}$

There isn't an element in $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ that is in $A$ or $B$, since the elements of the power sets are sets themselves, yet the elements in $A$ and $B$ aren't.
For example, let $Y = \{1\}$.
Am I misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a Powerset is the set of subsets. $$Y\in \mathcal P(A)\iff Y\subseteq A$$

Then too recall the definition of subset.$$Y\subseteq A {~\iff~ \forall x~(x\in Y\to x\in A) \\ ~\iff~ \forall x\in Y~(x\in A)}$$

Thus if $Y$ is an element of the powerset of $A$, then any element of $Y$ is an element of $A$, *et vice versa*.

---

So we have that:

$${\begin{array}{l|c:l}1&Y~\in~\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B) & \text{Assume}\\2& Y\in \mathcal P(A)~\wedge~ Y\in\mathcal P(B) & \text{Definition of Union}\\ 3&Y\subseteq A~~\wedge~~ Y\subseteq B & \text{Definition of Powerset}\\ \quad 4&\forall x\in Y~(x\in A)~\wedge~\forall x\in Y~( x\in B) & \text{Definition of Subset(eq)} \\\quad 5& \forall x\in Y~(x\in A\wedge x\in B) & \text{Distribution over universal quantifier} \\\quad 6&\forall x\in Y~(x\in (A\cap B)) &\text{Definition of intersection}\\ 7& Y~\subseteq ~(A\cap B) &\text{Definition of Suset(eq)}\\ 8& Y\in \mathcal P(A\cap B) & \text{Definition of Powerset} \end{array}\\... \text{and vice versa on every step}\\ Y\in\mathcal P(A)\cap \mathcal P(B)~ \iff ~Y\in \mathcal P(A\cap B)}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not stating that $Y$ is an element of $A$ and $B$, it is saying that every element $y \in Y$ is an element of $A$ and $B$. In your example $1 \in A$ and $1 \in B$.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to see that every element y of Y is an element of A and B

Comment: $Y\in\mathcal P(A)$ means $Y$ is a subset of $A$ , because the powerset is the set of subsets. Then by definition of subset, any element of $Y$ is an element of $A$.  Similarly any element of $Y$ is an element of $B$. , and so...$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{Y\in\mathcal P(A)}{Y\subseteq A}~\wedge~\dfrac{Y\in\mathcal P(B)}{Y\subseteq B}}{Y\subseteq(A\cap B)}}{Y\in\mathcal P(A\cap B)}$$